# How can i add two real numbers without use add.s/add.d in mips?

Tags: mips

I tried searching around the web but there doesn't seem to be any hope.

please help me? Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/128521/Indepth_IEEE_754_Multiplication_And_Addition.php

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute subtraction: A + B ==> A - (-B)